# Automatically adding specified text at beginning of files in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to have Visual Studio 2008 automatically add heading information to files? For example, "Copyright 2008" or something along those lines. I've been digging through the options, but nothing seems to be jumping out at me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you'd like to modify the class file templates.  They're in:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033
```

[More specific details here](http://blogs.southworks.net/jpgarcia/2008/09/01/visual-studio-2008-templates-compliant-with-microsoft-stylecop/)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but looks to be very useful for the future. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: My question was phrased poorly. I want to retroactively add the information to existing files, but the project isn't so huge that I can't do it manually. I'll make a code snippet that adds the header text I want. I assumed there was a per-solution setting I could specify.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution than modifying the template file directly. This utility allows you to create and save header/footer templates and apply them to entire source trees.

[C# Header Designer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HeaderDesigner) from MSDN Code Gallery